# best way to check a empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

How can I check an array recursively for empty content like this example:

```
Array
(
    [product_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

        )
    [product_data] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [price] => 
                )

        )

)
```

The array is not empty but there is no content.  How can I check this with a simple function?

Thank!!

Comment: How come your array has two identical keys `product_data` ?

Comment: @codaddict: Good Observation.

Comment: sorry i copied only the text for example :-)

Comment: P.S: i like this community more than others!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
function is_array_empty($InputVariable)
{
   $Result = true;

   if (is_array($InputVariable) && count($InputVariable) > 0)
   {
      foreach ($InputVariable as $Value)
      {
         $Result = $Result && is_array_empty($Value);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      $Result = empty($InputVariable);
   }

   return $Result;
}
```

Comment: A more general and fault tolerant solution than mine  :), but could you not short circuit it and return immediately on a non empty answer instead of continuing to test the rest of the array?

Comment: foreach ($InputVariable as $Value)

Comment: @David Martensson: The execution will only be routed to that else statement if the variable given to the function is not an array.  Think of the array given in the question as a tree and the else block as the base case that all leaves will be evaluated by.

Comment: Yes, but if it is an array it will complete the array and every array higher in the hierarchy even though it might already have found that its not empty. His example clearly specified that you could have empty rows but they should still be considered empty.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying.  Yes, you're right.  Once you find a non-empty element you should stop comparing and return false.  My implementation will needlessly continue to check for non-empty elements until it's traversed the whole structure.

Comment: @Sazzad Tushar Khan Thanks for spotting the typo

Answer (score 12):

If your array is only one level deep you can also do:

```
if (strlen(implode('', $array)) == 0)
```

Works in most cases :)

Comment: It is not. How about multi-dimension array?

Comment: @sonnb: You have to read carefully: One level != multi-dimension / multi level.

Answer (score 8):

Solution with array_walk_recursive:

```
function empty_recursive($value)
{
        if (is_array($value)) {
                $empty = TRUE;
                array_walk_recursive($value, function($item) use (&$empty) {
                        $empty = $empty && empty($item);
                });
        } else {
                $empty = empty($value);
        }
        return $empty;
}
```

Comment: Most elegant setup among the answers.

Comment: A clean and perfect solution to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the array will always contain the same type of data:

```
function TestNotEmpty($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $item)
        if(isset($item->title) || isset($item->descrtiption || isset($item->price))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short circuiting included.

```
function hasValues($input, $deepCheck = true) {
    foreach($input as $value) {
        if(is_array($value) && $deepCheck) {
            if($this->hasValues($value, $deepCheck))
                return true;
        }
        elseif(!empty($value) && !is_array($value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version. Once it finds a non-empty string in an array, it stops. Plus it properly checks on empty strings, so that a 0 (zero) is not considered an empty string (which would be if you used empty() function). By the way even using this function just for strings has proven invaluable over the years.

```
function isEmpty($stringOrArray) {
    if(is_array($stringOrArray)) {
        foreach($stringOrArray as $value) {
            if(!isEmpty($value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    return !strlen($stringOrArray);  // this properly checks on empty string ('')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this question and needs to check if the entire array is NULL, meaning that each pair in the array is equal to null, this is a handy function. You could very easily modify it to return true if any variable returns NULL as well. I needed this for a certain web form where it updated users data and it was possible for it to come through completely blank, therefor not needing to do any SQL.

```
$test_ary = array("1"=>NULL, "2"=>NULL, "3"=>NULL);

function array_empty($ary, $full_null=false){
    $null_count = 0;
    $ary_count = count($ary);

    foreach($ary as $value){
        if($value == NULL){
            $null_count++;
        }
    }

    if($full_null == true){
        if($null_count == $ary_count){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        if($null_count > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$test = array_empty($test_ary, $full_null=true);
echo $test;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=array_unique(array_values($args));
if(empty($arr[0]) && count($arr)==1){
 echo "empty array";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns `TRUE` if passed a variable other than an array, or if any of the nested arrays contains a value (including falsy values!). Returns `FALSE` otherwise.
Short circuits.

```
function has_values($var) {
  if (is_array($var)) {
    if (empty($var)) return FALSE;
    foreach ($var as $val) {
      if(has_values($val)) return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
  } 
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good utility function that will return `true (1)` if the array is empty, or `false (0)` if not:

```
function is_array_empty( $mixed ) {
    if ( is_array($mixed) ) {
        foreach ($mixed as $value) {
            if ( ! is_array_empty($value) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } elseif ( ! empty($mixed) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

For example, given a multidimensional array:

```
$products = array(
    'product_data' => array(
        0 => array(
            'title' => '',
            'description' => null,
            'price' => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

You'll get a `true` value returned from `is_array_empty()`, since there are no values set:

```
var_dump( is_array_empty($products) );
```

View this code interactively at: http://codepad.org/l2C0Efab

Answer (score 0):

I needed a function to filter an array recursively for non empty values.

Here is my recursive function:

```
function filterArray(array $array, bool $keepNonArrayValues = false): array {
  $result = [];
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $value = $this->filterArray($value, $keepNonArrayValues);
    }

    // keep non empty values anyway
    // otherwise only if it is not an array and flag $keepNonArrayValues is TRUE 
    if (!empty($value) || (!is_array($value) && $keepNonArrayValues)) {
      $result[$key] = $value;
    }
  }

  return array_slice($result, 0)
}
```

With parameter `$keepNonArrayValues` you can decide if values such `0` (number zero), `''` (empty string) or `false` (bool FALSE) shout be kept in the array. In other words: if `$keepNonArrayValues = true` only empty arrays will be removed from target array.

`array_slice($result, 0)` has the effect that numeric indices will be rearranged (0..length-1).

Additionally, after filtering the array by this function it can be tested with `empty($filterredArray)`.