# Check null values in array

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I've have the next array (a CakePHP array):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [username] => hank
    [password] => c9f3fa9ff1cc03389b960f877e9c909e6485ag6h
    [email] => user_email@hotmail.com
    [country] => 
    [city] =>
    [phone] => 666666666
    [other] =>
)
```

And I want to know if certain fields are NULL or empty (like `country` or `city`).
I've tried this:

In my controller:

```
...
$user = $this->User->findById($id);
$this->set('user', $user['User']); # $user['User'] returns the array seen before.
```

In my view

```
<?php $fields = array('country', 'city', 'phone'); ?>
<?php if (!in_array($fields, $user, true)): ?>
   <p>Bad, some fields of $fields are empty</p>
<?php else: ?>
  <p>Ok</p
<?php endif;?>
```

But this does not work. I need to know if any of the fields in `$fields` is NULL or empty.

Comment: Try using this answer, A custom build function:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4014414/1256403

Comment: `in_array` checks array values, not keys, and it takes strings as its needle, not arrays.

Comment: @Gordon do you mean `if (count(array_filter($fields)) !== count($array))` ?

Comment: @cbuckley needle may be an array

Comment: @enrmarc, yes, but that checks for the presence of an array within the array. OP wants to know if multiple string keys are present.

Comment: All comments about the signature of `in_array` are irrelevant; it is not the correct function to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you want something like this:

```
$fields = array('country', 'city', 'phone');
$check = array_filter(array_intersect_key($user, array_flip($fields)));

if (count($check) !== count($fields)) {
    // Bad; some fields are empty
} else {
    // OK
}
```

You could also pass a custom filter function; by default `array_filter` removes any values which equate to `false`.

**Edit**: [Here's an example](http://codepad.org/GmvO94SI).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you use in_array in the wrong way.

I suggest iterate over $fields and checks values in the $user:

```
<?php $bad_fields = false; ?>
<?php $fields = array('country', 'city', 'phone'); ?>
<?php foreach($fields as $field): ?>
<?php if !$user[$field]: ?>
<?php $bad_fields = true; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if $bad_fields: ?>
    <p>Bad, some fields of $fields are empty</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Ok</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that I could iterate over $fields but I was looking for something different.