# Best way to check if PHP Array is empty

Tags: php, optimization

This is mostly superficial but what's the **best** (faster performing, not personal preference or readability) way to check if an array is empty:

1. `count($arr) == 0`
2. `empty($arr)`
3. `$arr === array()`
4. Other?

My Guess is that

1. Iterates as far as possible then returns
2. Simply performs 1 after checking if the variable is an array
3. Seems like it should be slow as it has to construct a new object to compare with

But that doesn't account for any compile time optimizations that it performs here.

### Disclaimer

I'm not about to go through my code base changes all instances to the fastest possible method so please don't remind me it's micro optimzation. This is simple curiosity.

Comment: I'm guessing there's very little difference in most cases.  Personally though (and without testing) I suspect empty() is a tiny bit faster. The count() and finally the comparison.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014327/best-way-to-check-a-empty-array?rq=1

Comment: There is another topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216110/checking-for-empty-arrays-count-vs-empty

Comment: Simple `!$arr` is fastest, `empty()` is second, `=== array()` is third, `count` is distant fourth (5.4.3) But you're right, it's nothing more than micro-op.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use `count()` from benchmarks I've done in the past is slow as hell.

Comment: I disagree with the moderators.  Constructive Question.  empty() and !$ary are the fastest.  php 5.4 --- question is closed, so here are the benchmarks -- MIN: time ratio (1000x), fastest times (least scheduler interference)
Array
(
    [3."global $a; (empty($a))"] => 1.00x (3.886222839355469E-5)
    [2."global $a; (!$a)"] => 1.06x (4.100799560546875E-5)
    [4."global $a; (!isset($a[0]))"] => 1.29x (5.006790161132812E-5)
    [1."global $a; ($a === array())"] => 1.44x (5.602836608886719E-5)
    [5."global $a; (count($a))"] => 4.89x (0.0001900196075439453)
)

Answer (score 2):

```
    if(empty($arr))
    echo "Empty";
    else
    echo "Ok..!";
```

This is the fastest and secure way to check an array  empty or not

Comment: Did you do any benchmarks or something ?

Comment: Actually, `!$array` is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

an empty array is:

```
    $emptyArray = array();
```

check its empty:

```
    if( empty( $emptyArray ) ){

         echo 'array is empty';

    }
```

if array is not empty:

```
    $notEmptyArray = array( 'item' );
```

check its not empty:

```
    if( !empty( $notEmptyArray ) ){

         echo 'array not empty';

    }
```

there are other ways of doing it, but the empty function built for this sort of thing.