# Easiest way to check if PHP array is not empty

Tags: php, arrays

How do I check that a PHP array is not empty?

```
// If $columns array is not empty...

foreach ($columns as $column) {
  echo $column;
}
```

Comment: I dont know why the vote to close... So far, three different answers with three different solutions. This is obviously not as simple a question as it first appears. I know there are many ways of checking for an empty array, but there is a lot of debate as to the simplest, most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: It's actually a very simple question (despite there being several different answers, each of which will work), and well documented in the php docs, which is probably why the vote to close

Comment: I don't think it gets much simpler than `if($array)`. count would be bad for large arrays, however empty is a good solution as well.

Comment: Related/Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202553/best-way-to-check-if-php-array-is-empty?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014327/best-way-to-check-a-empty-array?lq=1 and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216110/checking-for-empty-arrays-count-vs-empty?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: using `empty()` function.

```
if (!empty($columns)){
   foreach ($columns as $column) {
      echo $column;
   }
}
```

Also can be used with other types than array.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with functions? Empty arrays will simply return false:

```
if ($array) {
    // array is not empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`count()`](https://www.php.net/count)

```
if (count($columns) > 0) {
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        echo $column;
    }
}
```