# how to test if all values in a two dimensional array are empty with php

Tags: php, arrays

i have a situation where in oder to save data from a form to the session i have to check if the $errors array which stores errors genarated by the checks done on the form data is empty.

the problem is the array is an associative array an when i use the 'empty function' to test if the array is empty it always returns flase even when all the values in the array are empty, what can i do to check if the associative array is empty, below is my code

```
session_start();

// define errors array 
$errors = array(
'name' => "",
'username' => "",
'age' => "");

// check and sanitize form data
if (isset($_POST["name"]) and empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $errors['name'] = "your name is needed";
     }else{
         $_POST['name'] = test_input($_POST['name']);
         if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zéèàêâùïüë.',_  ]+$/",$_POST['name'])) {
             $errors['name'] = "only letters and white spaces accepted";
             }else{
                $validator++; 
             }
     }

    if (isset($_POST["username"]) and empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $errors['username'] = "your username is needed";
     }else{
         $_POST['username'] = test_input($_POST['username']);
         if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zéèàêâùïüë.',_  ]+$/",$_POST['username'])) {
             $errors['username'] = "only letters and white spaces accepted";
             }else{
                $validator++; 
             }
     }

    if (isset($_POST["age"]) and empty($_POST["age"])) {
         $errors['age'] = "age is needed";
     }else{
         $_POST['age'] = test_input($_POST['age']);
         if(!preg_match("/^[1-90]+$/",$_POST['age'])) {
           $errors['age'] = "only numbers accepted";
             }else{
                $validator++; 
             }
     }
// check if data is correct and save to session
if(empty($errors)){
    // save data in session 
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['age'] = $_POST["age"];
}else{
    session_destroy();
    header("location :index.php");
}`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to check a empty array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014327/best-way-to-check-a-empty-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have initialized the `$errors` with its keys, it will return false when checked if empty. Instead the best way to do this would be.

```
$errors = array();
// if error occurs then $errors["name"] = "Name error";
// Now you can check if $errors is empty or not
if(empty($errors)){
  // store it to session
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to define errors array as

```
// define errors array 
$errors = array();
```

Then your condition to check if there are no errors will work perfect

```
// check if data is correct and save to session
if(empty($errors)){
      // Logic 
}
```

Your code can further be optimized by removing `isset` from each of your conditions. Below line of code can be improved.

Original version

```
if (isset($_POST["name"]) and empty($_POST["name"])) {
    // Logic
}
```

Improved version

```
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    // Logic 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define

```
$errors = array();
```

instead of

```
$errors = array(
'name' => "",
'username' => "",
'age' => "");
```

and then do you validation and can check with `empty($errors)` or `count($errors)`

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter()` without a callback removes the empty elements.  So you could do something like...

```
if( empty( array_filter($errors))){
    // save data in session 
}
```